# como puedo darle estilos a un boton radio que sea tipo checkbox

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, checkbox

tengo un boton radio que me oculta y me muestra contenido pero quisiera agregarle estilos tipo checkbox pero no se como hacerlo o de otro modo cambiar que sea a tipo checkbox pero solo quiero que al estar presionado solo me muestre la info oculta de ese checkbox a la vez

```css
  .content {
    display: none;
}


input:checked#unico + span, 

 input:checked#unico + input { 

    display: block; 

}


input#unico  {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;

  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;

  border: 2px solid #999;
  transition: 0.2s all linear;
  margin-right: 5px;

  position: relative;
  top: 4px;
}

 input:checked#unico  {
  border: 6px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div style="display: inline;" >
    <label>
         <input  id="unico" type="radio" name="p" value=""  class="trigger" data-rel="abc" required="" />contenido1
         <span class="abc content">
    contenido oculto
       </span>
        </label>
        </div>
    <br>
       <div style="display: inline;" >
        <label>
         <input  id="unico" type="radio" name="p" value=""  class="trigger" data-rel="abc" required="" />contenido2
         <span class="abc content">
    contenido oculto
       </span>
        </label>
</div>
```

quiero que se pueda seleccionar uno a la vez y que al darle sobre el checkbox solo me muestre el contenido de uno y si selecciono el otro se me oculte el que estaba seleccionado y se me muestre el contenido del otro algo asi como un si y no pero con checkbox

Comment: Deseas que se muestren como checkboxes (solo ajuste visual) o cambiar los inputs a tipo checkbox y mantener la funcionalidad?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes ocultar tus input de tipo radio y crear uno personalizado:

```css
.container {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 35px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 22px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

/* Hide the browser's default radio button */
.container input {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Create a custom radio button */
.checkmark {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: #eee;
}

/* On mouse-over, add a grey background color */
.container:hover input ~ .checkmark {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

/* When the radio button is checked, add a blue background */
.container input:checked ~ .checkmark {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

/* Create the indicator (the dot/circle - hidden when not checked) */
.checkmark:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

/* Show the indicator (dot/circle) when checked */
.container input:checked ~ .checkmark:after {
  display: block;
}

/* Style the indicator (dot/circle) */
.container .checkmark:after {
    left: 9px;
  top: 5px;
  width: 5px;
  height: 10px;
  border: solid white;
  border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<h1>Custom Radio Buttons</h1>
<label class="container">One
  <input type="radio" checked="checked" name="radio">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<label class="container">Two
  <input type="radio" name="radio">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<label class="container">Three
  <input type="radio" name="radio">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<label class="container">Four
  <input type="radio" name="radio">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
```